# Batch: Separate numbers from characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering if anyone knows a good way to separate numbers from characters or remove the characters so they can be stored in a variable using only Batch in Windows so it looks something like the following...

Input:

```
1A
12B
16BA
16BB
31C
```

Output:

```
A
B
BA
BB
C
```

Comment: Your example shows output with the 'numbers' removed from the 'characters', but your question asks to remove the 'characters' from the 'numbers'; which is it? Also you mention variables, which means that you've already got a task in mind, can you please share it and post the code that you've written to perform the task, but which currently fails to do so? Unless yoiu're able to do that, your question will be taken as a straight code request, which on StackOverflow is off topic. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly post some of your efforts/code then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found what I was looking for.

Input:

```
SET test=016BA
FOR /F "delims=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" %%G IN ("%test%") DO SET position=%%G
echo Position: %position%
pause
```

Output:

```
Position: BA
```

Comment: Close but not correct, change the loop options to `delims=0123456789` (otherwise the `,` is a delimiter too; adding `eol=0` would further avoid the default `eol` character `;`); and consider what should happen with something like `12AB3C4DE5`; do you want to return `AB3C4DE5` (so add loop option `tokens=*`), or just `AB` (do not any loop options, so the default `tokens=1` applies)?

Answer (score 0):

If you need set a variable with only non number in same string:

---

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & title %~0

:: get non number in variable with same name in loop :: 
for %%S in (1A 12B 16BA 16BB 31C) do ( for /f %%n in ('
cmd/u/c echo="%%~S"^<nul^|find /v " "^|findstr /v [0-9]
')do set "_%%S=!_%%S!%%~n")&& echo/Position _%%S=!_%%S!
```

---

- Output:

  ---

```
Position _1A=A
Position _12B=B
Position _16BA=BA
Position _16BB=BB
Position _31C=C
```

---